# no termino de comprender como usar ajax en este caso

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, django, return

cuando le doy like a las publicaciones funciona correctamete mi codigo ajax. el problema viene cuando intento hacer lo mismo con los comentarios de las publicaciones, el problema es que no se como acceder a lo datos, ya que no es solo un comentario, son muchos, en la publicacion solo es una a la vez, en lo comentarios no ocurre lo mismo, como hago para que funcione?, que al momento de dale like a un comentario no se recargue toda mi pagina, solamente ese pedazo con ajax?

mi view es:

```
class AddCommentLike(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        activate('es')  # Establece el contexto de traducción en español
        comment = SocialComment.objects.get(pk=pk)
        post = comment.post

        is_dislike = False
        for dislike in comment.dislikes.all():
            if dislike == request.user:
                is_dislike = True
                break

        if is_dislike:
            comment.dislikes.remove(request.user)

        is_like = False
        for like in comment.likes.all():
            if like == request.user:
                is_like = True
                break
        
        if not is_like:
            userde = request.user##
            userpara = comment.author
            ver = post.pk
            context = f' a {userde} le gusto tu comentario: {comment.comment[:15]}...'##
            Notification(userde, userpara, context, ver, request)##
            comment.likes.add(request.user)

        if is_like:
            comment.likes.remove(request.user)

        comment_dislike_count = comment.dislikes.count()

        #contar los likes poara retornar al javascript
        comment_like_count = comment.likes.count()

        # Construir la respuesta en formato JSON
        response_data = {
            'disliked': not is_dislike,
            'dislike_count': comment_dislike_count,
            #like coun
            'like_count': comment_like_count
        }

        return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

y mi url esta asi:

```
path('post/<int:post_pk>/comment/<int:pk>/like', AddCommentLike.as_view(), name="comment-like"),
```

y mi html del like:

```
<button id="like-btn-comment-{{ comment.pk }}" type="submit" class="comment-like-btn flex space-x-2 justify-center items-center hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-dark-third text-xs py-2 rounded-lg cursor-pointer text-gray-500 dark:text-dark-txt">
                                {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                                    {% if request.user in comment.likes.all %}
                                        <i class='bx bx-like text-blue-600'></i><span class="text-blue-600">{{comment.likes.all.count}}</span>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <i class='bx bx-like'></i><span>{{comment.likes.all.count}}</span>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endif %}
                                <p class="text-sm font-semibold"></p>
                            </button>
```

Comment: Cuál es, **específicamente**, tu pregunta?

Comment: como puedo hacer para que no se recargue la pagina cuando le doy like a un comentario

Comment: Entonces, cambia el título de la pregunta. *"no termino de comprender como usar ajax en este caso"* no es una pregunta. Suena más a un comentario.

Comment: Supongo cada comentario tiene su boton de dar like, simplemente puedes añadirle al contenedor de los botones un evento de tipo click y que el evento se propague para sus subelementos esto con el fin de tener un solo evento en vez de tener 50, a su vez, cada boton o contenedor que tiene la informacion de los likes relacionada debes ponerle una clase común, como por ejemplo `class = 'boton-like'`, utilizas entonces jquery (si lo estas usando) o en su defecto javascript vanilla para recuperar el elemento especifico utilizando el evento